# Skewed graph after rotating points

Tags: python

I am trying to rotate a series of points around the origin given an angle in radians, but the results always give a skewed version of the graph.

Here is the method I am using, it is a pandas data frame containing x and y values:

```py
df['x'] = df['x']*math.cos(math.radians(45))-df['y']*math.sin(math.radians(45))
df['y'] = df['x']*math.sin(math.radians(45))+df['y']*math.cos(math.radians(45))
```

I don't understand why it is creating a skewed graph.

Comment: Are you using the same variables on left and right side of assignment? So, the 2nd line uses the new `df['x']`, does it? That's wrong. Use another variable for left hand side (at least for `df['x']`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['x'] = df['x']*math.cos(math.radians(45))-df['y']*math.sin(math.radians(45))
```

`df['x']` is overridden with the new value.

So, the 2nd line uses the new `df['x']` but that's wrong. It should use the old value instead.

```
df['y'] = df['x']*math.sin(math.radians(45))+df['y']*math.cos(math.radians(45))
```

Using at temporary should fix this:

```
dfx = df['x']*math.cos(math.radians(45))-df['y']*math.sin(math.radians(45))
df['y'] = df['x']*math.sin(math.radians(45))+df['y']*math.cos(math.radians(45))
df['x'] = dfx
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I cant believe I was making such a simple mistake